# Comunication between Host and Docker Container using FIFO pipes by bind mount (Linux)

Tags: c++, docker, dockerfile, pipe, mkfifo

My container creates fifo pipe in the bind mounted dir but container when reads or writes to this pipe, the host cant receive it or vice versa. with similar permissions to create or open pipe works for communication within host and within container. But it does not work in between host and container.

The pipe is created and reads/writes in cpp program within container. Pipe created with both 666 and 777 permissions and opened with O_RDWR. Similar cpp programs reads/writes in the host. Again these program works fine within container and within host the problem happens only in host communication.

```
docker run -it --name broken-container -v /tmp:/app2 cppdocker
```

Comment: Are you forced to use pipes? With docker containers something like gRPC seems more appropiate to me. (no file rights needed). [introduction to gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/)

Comment: What "kind" of Docker are you using?  If you're directly using the Docker Engine on native Linux I would expect this to work, but if you have a VM-based solution like Docker Desktop, the named pipe can't cross the VM boundary.  Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Yep,  Kind of a requirement.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have both but I am ruuning cmds like docker run or docker build which are executed by docker engine as far as i know.

Comment: @DavidMaze
send.cpp Dockerfle just compiles it 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int fd;
    const char* pipeName = "/app2/my_pipe"; // Pipe file path
    fd = open(pipeName, O_RDWR);
    char * message = "hello";
    int check = write(fd, message, strlen(message) + 1);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

Comment: @DavidMaze
recieve.cpp runs on host
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    const char* pipeName = "/tmp/my_pipe";
    int val = mkfifo(pipeName, 0777);
    char buffer[80];
    int fd = open(pipeName, O_RDWR);
    ssize_t bytesRead = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
    buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
    close(fd);
    std::cout << "Received message: " << buffer << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: Stated more directly: if you're using Docker Desktop this won't work; and if you're on native Linux then you don't need Docker Desktop.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have removed Docker Desktop Reinstalled only Docker Engine. Bulid and Run it again still don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comments in response to questions from other users, I suspect you're running into the issue that the file permissions you supply to `mknod()` (or `creat()`/`mkdir()` when creating regular files / directories) are still masked by your process's [umask](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html). Combine that with the fact docker runs the containers under a different user than the user you're using from the outside, you're likely running into a "permission denied" situation.

Other than "does not work" you didn't post any error message, and the example code you are using doesn't contain any error checking of the system calls you are using. **Always check for errors when calling operating system functions!** Even so, you'd have noticed the failures had you run your programs through `strace`, which would give you some feedback as to which operations fail.

Assuming that my guess here is correct and you are really running into actual permission problems due to the umask, I've taken the example code you've posted and changed three things:

- I've added very trivial error checking to it via [perror()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) so that you get at least some feedback when something fails.
- I've changed the `read()` and `write()` system calls to properly handle the `EINTR` corner case, as well as the `write()` system call to loop until all bytes have been written. (This is considered best practice when using blocking reads/writes.)
- I've added [fchmod()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) after opening the FIFO on the receiver side (where it's also created) to ensure that the file mode of the FIFO is actually changed to the desired value `0777`. (I would recommend to do this over changing the `umask` of the process, though you could also do that before calling `mknod`.)

Your receiver code adjusted:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    static char const* pipeName = "/inside/container/my_pipe";

    int rc = mkfifo(pipeName, 0777);
    // ignore EEXIST (file already exists)
    // since that isn't really an error
    if (rc < 0 && errno != EEXIST) {
        perror("mkfifo");
        return 1;
    }

    int fd = open(pipeName, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return 2;
    }

    // force 0777 permissions on the device (since the
    // process's umask likely caused the actual permissions
    // to be lesser)
    rc = fchmod(fd, 0777);
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("fchmod");
        close(fd);
        return 2;
    }

    char buffer[80];

    // Properly handle "interrupted system call" in blocking mode
    // with a loop
    ssize_t bytesRead = -1;
    errno = EINTR;
    while (bytesRead < 0 && errno == EINTR)
        bytesRead = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);

    if (bytesRead < 0) {
        perror("read");
        close(fd);
        return 3;
    }

    // For long enough messages the kernel is free to split
    // up any data that was sent by the other side, so this
    // initial read may only contain partial data. Keep that
    // in mind when designing your application.

    buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
    close(fd);

    std::cout << "Received message: " << buffer << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Your sender code adjusted:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    static char const* pipeName = "/outside/container/my_pipe"; // Pipe file path
    int fd = open(pipeName, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    static char const* message = "hello";
    char const* ptr = message;
    size_t remaining = strlen(message) + 1;

    // Loop to ensure that we write all of the data
    // Since write() is blocking anyway this appears
    // to be the desired behavior?.
    // For short messages like this example this will
    // typically execute the loop only once.
    while (remaining > 0) {
        ssize_t bytesWritten = write(fd, ptr, remaining);
        if (bytesWritten < 0) {
            // Properly handle the "interrupted system call"
            // condition
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            perror("write");
            close(fd);
            return 2;
        }
        remaining -= static_cast<size_t>(bytesWritten);
        ptr += static_cast<size_t>(bytesWritten);
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Running this on my system with a standard Docker container (no customization) works.

And if my guess is wrong and it's not the `umask` you'll at least get a proper error message why the operation failed.